# 3des with 2 different keys in java getting null

Tags: java

3des with 2 different keys in java getting null.

```
import java.security.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class DESedeEncryption {
public static void main(String[] args) {

SecretKey k1 = generateDESkey();
SecretKey k2 = generateDESkey();

String firstEncryption = desEncryption("plaintext", k1);
System.out.println("firstEncryption Value : "+firstEncryption);
String decryption = desDecryption(firstEncryption, k2);
System.out.println("decryption Value : "+decryption);
String secondEncryption = desEncryption(decryption, k1);
System.out.println("secondEncryption Value : "+secondEncryption);

}

public static SecretKey generateDESkey() {
KeyGenerator keyGen = null;
try {
    keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
} catch (Exception ex) {     
}
keyGen.init(112); // key length 56
SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
return secretKey;
}

public static String desEncryption(String strToEncrypt, SecretKey desKey) {
try {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
    BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes());
    String encryptedString =base64encoder.encode(encryptedText);
    return encryptedString;
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
return null;
}

public static String desDecryption(String strToDecrypt, SecretKey desKey) {
try {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
    BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] encryptedText = base64decoder.decodeBuffer(strToDecrypt);
    byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
    String decryptedString= bytes2String(plainText);
    return decryptedString;
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
return null;
}

 private static String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i <bytes.length; i++) {
        stringBuffer.append((char) bytes[i]);
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
}
```

while i'm running the above code i'm getting null values. plz help.

output:

firstEncryption Value : jAihaGgiOzBSFwBWo3gpbw==

decryption Value : null

secondEncryption Value : null

```
getting error:

firstEncryption Value : ygGPwCllarWvSH8td55j/w==
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineDoFinal(DESedeCipher.java:
294)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at DESedeEncryption.desDecryption(DESedeEncryption.java:145)
    at DESedeEncryption.main(DESedeEncryption.java:107)
decryption Value : null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DESedeEncryption.desEncryption(DESedeEncryption.java:130)
    at DESedeEncryption.main(DESedeEncryption.java:109)
secondEncryption Value : null
```

Answer (score -1):

Symmetric ciphers work by encrypting and decrypting with the same key, hence the name symmetric. (And for most modes also the same IV, but the IV doesn't need to be secret.) You're encrypting with one key and decrypting with an independent key which is different with overwhelming probability (i.e. it might the same once a zillion quillion eternities). That won't work.

Perhaps you are confused by the description of Triple-DES also known as 3DES DESede or TDEA. The original DES (or DEA) cipher uses a 56-bit key (in 8 bytes) which was secure in the 1960s but not now. Triple-DES was defined using DES as a building block but with a bundle of 3 keys (k1,k2,k3) which can also be treated as a combined 168-bit key (in 24 bytes); if k3=k1 the key is described as 112-bits although it is still stored as 24 bytes. Your call to KeyGenerator "DESede" .init(112) does exactly that; it generates a 24-byte bundle with k3=k1 and k2 different. For convenience in the past Triple-DES is defined to use single-DES to encrypt with k1, decrypt with k2, and encrypt with k3, and the reverse when decrypting, hence the name DES-EDE or DESede. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES .

If you really want, you can implement Triple-DES yourself in Java using Cipher "DES" by doing E,D,E (or reverse D,E,D if used) and then wrapping the mode around that, see [Java Triple DES encryption with 2 different keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610358/java-triple-des-encryption-with-2-different-keys) . But it's much easier to just use Cipher "DESede", which it does the lot for you, treating DESede like any other symmetric cipher primitive, as answered in that question.

Also, mode ECB is dangerous. It is an exaggeration to say it is always insecure as some people do, but historically very many applications using it designed by non-experts are insecure. Unless you know much more than is evident in your question, or are following (or interfacing to) a design by someone who does, use a better established mode like CBC or CTR.